# System V shared memory permission bits: meaning, and how to change

Tags: c, unix, shared-memory, sysv-ipc

I know that when i create a shared memory block, we set the permission so that every proccess can read and write in that block with 0777 (no idea why, my teacher just said to use it like that).

I'm creating with shmget as:

```
shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(server_config), IPC_CREAT|0777)
```

However I'd like to know:

- What each number means
- How to change the flag after the shared memory block is created
- How to only allow 1 proccess to write, while all the other proccesses can only read

Comment: Please clarify exactly how you are creating the shared memory block; the answer depends on whether you're using the old System V API for shared memory, the newer POSIX API, or something else.  ("0777" very strongly implies that this is something Unixy, *not* Windows, but if I'm wrong about that, please say so.)

Comment: @zowl it's clear, like when I was studying modern physics my teacher said that the separation constants for Schroedinger Equaition's solutions of the H atom were to be as they were and I wasn't happy at all and solved the equation to understand WHY?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what we needed to know, thank you.  (`shmget` is part of the "old System V API.")

Comment: @iharob I know what Unix mode bits mean, but the other two parts of the question required the clarification to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an octal number of `OR`ed options the same ones that you use for directory permissions.

This is their meaning ([source](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php))

```
rwx rwx rwx = 111 111 111
rw- rw- rw- = 110 110 110
rwx --- --- = 111 000 000

and so on...

rwx = 111 in binary = 7
rw- = 110 in binary = 6
r-x = 101 in binary = 5
r-- = 100 in binary = 4
```

Where of course, `r` stands for *read* and `w` for *write* then `x` means *execute*.

There are also constants defined with these values (see man [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html))

```
S_IRWXU  00700 user (file owner) has read, write and execute permission
S_IRUSR  00400 user has read permission
S_IWUSR  00200 user has write permission
S_IXUSR  00100 user has execute permission
S_IRWXG  00070 group has read, write and execute permission
S_IRGRP  00040 group has read permission
S_IWGRP  00020 group has write permission
S_IXGRP  00010 group has execute permission
S_IRWXO  00007 others have read, write and execute permission
S_IROTH  00004 others have read permission
S_IWOTH  00002 others have write permission
S_IXOTH  00001 others have execute permission
```

As you can see `0777` has a leading `0` because it's octal and is equivalent to `S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO`.

To answer your other two questions:

- You can change the permissions on a shared memory block with [`shmctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmctl).  It goes something like this -- completely untested, may be buggy:

  ```
  int change_shm_perm(int shmid, mode_t new_permissions)
  {
    struct shmid_ds buf;
    if (shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, &buf)) {
      perror("shmctl(IPC_STAT)");
      return -1;
    }
    buf.shm_perm = (buf.shm_perm & ~0777) | (new_permissions & 0777);
    if (shmctl(shmid, IPC_SET, &buf)) {
      perror("shmctl(IPC_SET)");
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- To allow only one process to write, while all others can only read, the process with write privileges must run under its own uid.  Then you have that process create the memory segment and set its permissions to `0644`.  It should be clear from the explanation of mode bits why this has the desired effect.

Comment: Too bad it's not possible to accept two answers. But I have a solution if you don't mind. What do you think?

Comment: @zwol I'm assuming that the second part means that the one that creates it is the one that can write?
Also, could you test it? I'd say that the buf.perm would be buf.shm_perm, but I'm not sure because I never hear of shmctl

Comment: @iharob Shall we do it the other way around, maybe?  You need the imaginary internet points more than I do ;-)

Comment: @AndréAlmeida Yes, the one that creates it is the one that can write, *as long as* all the other programs are running under different user IDs.  There's no way to prevent other programs running with the *same* uid from being able to write.  And you're quite right, `buf.perm` should be `buf.shm_perm`, that was sloppy of me.  I'm sorry, I do not have time to work up a complete test program for this.

Comment: @zwol I don't need them, or at least I want to think that way.